# while I was trying to train a DeepSpeech model on google colab, I'm getting an error saying that .whl file is not suported

Tags: python, mozilla-deepspeech

commands i used

```
!wget https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/download/v0.9.3/ds_ctcdecoder-0.9.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

!pip install /content/~path~/ds_ctcdecoder-0.9.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

this gives me an error

> ERROR: ds_ctcdecoder-0.9.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

how can i solve this ?

Comment: Why not `pip install deepspeech`?

Comment: https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/

Comment: https://progur.com/2018/02/how-to-use-mozilla-deepspeech-tutorial.html

Comment: Please post the `python` version and the `pip` version you are using. The error is likely related to either the `python` version (is it 3.6? The `.whl` is built for 3.6). Older `pip` versions can also cause this error.

Comment: my python version is  - Python 3.7.10 
                                     and pip 21.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `wget` to pull down a `.whl` file that was built for a different version of Python. You are pulling down

`ds_ctcdecoder-0.9.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

but are running Python 3.7. You need a different `.whl` file, such as:

`ds_ctcdecoder-0.9.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

This is [available here from the DeepSpeech releases page on GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/download/v0.9.3/deepspeech-0.9.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl).